# Analyze if the limit exists: $\lim_{x\rightarrow0, x>0}\sqrt{x}\cdot \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits, functions

> Analyze if the limit for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ exists and calculate it if
>   it does:
>
> $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0, x>0}\sqrt{x}\cdot \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

For $x\rightarrow 0$:

$\sqrt{x}$ will converge to $0$ and $\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ will diverge because it will always change its sign.

$\Rightarrow$ The complete term will diverge

For $x>0$:

$\sqrt{x}$ will diverge to $\infty$ and $\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ will converge because $\lim_{x>0}\frac{1}{x}=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $\sin(0)=0$ and $\infty\cdot0=0$

$\Rightarrow$ The complete term will converge

Did I do everything correctly?

Comment: That's not what $$\lim_{x\to0,x>0}$$ means. Is means just "the limit as $x$ goes to zero, for positive $x$".

Comment: So it means that x goes to positive zero?

Comment: If "positive zero" is something that even makes sense... But essentially, yes.

Comment: It's not true that $\lim_{x \to 0, x>0}\frac{1}{x}=0$.

Comment: Olivier, what is it then?
I think $\lim_{x\rightarrow0, x>0}\frac{1}{x}=+\infty$
Correct?

Comment: Thank you both Arthur Olivier Oloa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, what you wrote is not correct.

A possible route is to just observe that
$$
\left|\sqrt{x}\cdot \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right|\le \sqrt{x}
$$ then letting $x \to 0^+$.

Comment: @cnmesr We don't have $\lim_{x\rightarrow0, x>0}\sin\left( {\frac{1}{x}}\right )=0$, this is wrong.

Comment: $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0, x>0}\sqrt{x} \cdot \lim_{x\rightarrow0, x>0}sin\left( {\frac{1}{x}}\right )=0\cdot sin \left(\infty \right )=0$$

Comment: It's better to write $\left|\lim_{x\rightarrow0, x>0}\left(\sqrt{x} \cdot\sin\left( {\frac{1}{x}}\right )\right)\right|\le \lim_{x\rightarrow0, x>0}\sqrt{x}=0.$

Comment: I think limit no exist because sinus of infinity has different signs, this multiplied by small value (almost zero) will still have different signs, thats why no limit, right?

Comment: Yes $\sin (1/x)$ is wildly oscillating as $x \to 0$, but it is absoulutely *bounded* by 1...

Comment: So my comment is right or not? I think is right.
I don't want use other solution, try to use my, and thank you very much for help :)

Comment: Your comment above is not so clear, not right to me. IMO the simple way to obtain the sought limit is to proceed as in my answer. Thank you.